# Rollback from proprietary to open source ATI drivers causes Unity to not start anymore

Tags: 11.10, drivers, ati, proprietary, open-source

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10.

I changed the open drivers for the proprietary ones and had all sorts of problems while trying to make dual screens work, so I decided to roll back the drivers.

Now Unity won't start and if I run `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` I get:

`/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

I tried mostly everything that was suggested on the net with the purge and everything. 
Installing `ccsm` and adding the Unity plugin did not work. I also just learned about that missing file while writing this question, so thats where I'm heading now.

If you need more info just say so.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "that missing file"?

Comment: I meant the file from the error message I receive when running unity_support_test -p : libGL.so.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little googling,

I got to this url: http://www.x.org/wiki/radeonBuildHowTo#Removing_AMD.2BAC8-ATI_catalyst.2BAC8-fglrx_driver_.28closed_source.29

Which didn't work but made me google the new error and found:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/859188

There is a filed bug about it and the workaround is:

```
apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The solution I followed was similar to that listed above, but had a couple extra steps. 
I did them, not knowing if the simpler one-liner would have been enough:

http://onubuntu.blogspot.com/2011/10/manually-removing-fglrx-from-ubuntu.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.